# Android Development start

Tags: android

when creating a new android application project..a by default activity should be created in my "src" folder .. 
but when i created new project there is no any default activity... i have chose "blank activity " too.. what can i do for this ?? 
and its compulsory that a by default activity must be created according to this official site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
please help

Comment: Yea this has started happening in my eclipse as well. Very odd. Simple to create your own though.

Right click src and create a new package. Preferably com.example.myapp (or whatever your package is). Inside this package create class ActivityMain.
Add this ActivityMain to your Manifest.
Create a corresponding layout file and you should be ready to go.

There are plenty of tutorials out there for the details of these files. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class that extends Activity.

In your manifest file add

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Make sure the `android:name` field is correct for your application. For me `MyActivity` is the name of my activity and `activities` is a subpackage.
From here on you can start like normally.

If you still have problems, you can just look for an example and copy the file.